# scrollTo has no animation on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

For some reason calling `scrollTo({x: 50})` on `ScrollView` and `scrollToOffset({offset: 50})` on `FlatList` has no animation on Android only.

```
const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);
...
const handleOnPress = useCallback(
  (data) => {
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollToOffset({offset: getOffset(data)});
    ...
  },
  [getOffset]
);
...
<ScrollView
  ref={scrollViewRef}
  ...
>
  <MyItem onPress={handleOnPress}/>
<ScrollView/>
```

The same problem happens when using `FlatList` with the proper adjustments.

Comment: By default **animated** is true but try to set it manually.

Comment: Thanks @LeriGogsadze, I did try that. See my answer for what was my problem.

Comment: Can you give me a snack url?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had two calls to the `scrollTo` method (somewhere else in the code), equivalent example:

```
const handleOnPress = useCallback(
  (data) => {
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollToOffset({offset: getOffset(data)});
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollToOffset({offset: getOffset(data)});
    ...
  },
  [getOffset]
);
```

And for some reason this caused the Android animation not to work.